# clGetProfilingEventInfo: How to get multiple profiling info?

Tags: profiling, opencl

I would like to get profiling info. My commandqueue is already enabled for profiling.

This is my code:

```
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
    commandQueue,
    kernl,
    2,
    NULL,
    globalThreads,
    localThreads,
    0,
    NULL,
    &ndrEvt);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed.");

//Won't proceed ahead if all work-items have not finished processing; Synchronization point
status = clFinish(commandQueue);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clFlush failed.");

//fetch performance data

clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_start2, NULL);

//clRetainEvent(ndrEvt);

clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_end2, NULL);
single_exec_time2 = time_end2 - time_start2;

clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_end, NULL);
single_exec_time = time_end - time_start2;
```

Signle_exec_time_2 shows me a correct result, but single_exec_time = 0.

I think the problem lies in event handling, the reference count of ndrEvt goes to zero.

**I've tried to introduce clRetainEvent(ndrEvt) (you can see it as comment) and it "worked", so at this point I'm wondering if introducing clRetainEvent() would give me the right result?**

Comment: Have you _verified_ the refcount goes to zero, or just think it might be? You can check it with `clGetEventInfo`. I doubt it is the problem. Check the status codes you get back from `clGetEventProfilingInfo` (with CL_EVENT_REFERENCE_COUNT) as well as the individual values you get back (before the subtractions).

Comment: I've encountered same error on different platform - sometimes CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED & CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT profile info is broken - Device time counters were bigger than that for CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START & CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END. Code looks ok, so I advice you to check start & end time counters. If they are OK, possibly, you're facing some bugs.

Comment: @Dithermaster I played around with clGetEventInfo(..., CL_EVENT_REFERENCE_COUNT) status = 0 (I think it is CL_SUCCESS) and refcount gives me always 1, and even if I put clRetainEvent() it doesn't change anyway (that's weird I cann't explain this behavior). The most strange thing I haven't changed nothing, only inserted some clGetEventInfo() around, IT JUST WORKS!

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan I experienced your same problem, and had some unrealistic values in variables, then I don't know how it's gone. To explain why _Device time counters were bigger than that for CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START & CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END_ because I think you have placed bad variables (Like it happened to me). I write the code under this comment.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan try this and put in clGetEventProfilingInfo missing info:
clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt, COMMAND_QUEUED, &time_queued); clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt, COMMAND_SUBMIT, &time_submit); clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt,COMMAND_START,&time_start); clGetEventProfilingInfo(ndrEvt, COMMAND_END, &time_end); single_exec_time = time_end - time_start; 
single_setup_time = time_submit - time_queued; 
single_total_time = time_end - time_queued;